# .NET Process can't create ActiveX Object

Tags: c#, .net, com, sccm

I'm hitting a wall that I understand.  I have a simple COM server that I want to instantiate.  I can do so with simple VBS or PS commands outside of my EXE:

```
$sms_client = New-Object -COM 'CPApplet.CPAppletMgr'

Set controlPanelAppletManager = CreateObject("CPApplet.CPAppletMgr")
```

In my C# code I tried early binding, late binding, a PS runspace/pipeline and lastly Process.Start( cscript myVBS ).   In all of those scenarios it comes back with class not registered and fails.

```
//throws exception
CPAPPLETLib.CPAppletMgr cpAppletMgr= new CPAPPLETLib.CPAppletMgr();

// myType does not come back null
Type myType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("CPApplet.CPAppletMgr");
// throws exception
object myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

Update: I can create the Scripting.FileSystemObject without issue. I don't need that... it was just a test.

I've tried compiling 32bit, 64bit.  Running as standard user and elevated.  I've tried registering the DLL again but something about my C# .NET EXE is doing something that it just can't see the COM.  I even tried creating a brand new console app project and it does it there also.

Am I missing something that is a .NET 101 COM-Interop fundamental?

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {096C5BA8-044B-4BAC-9914-144723BA4F2A} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

Update:

Setting the platform to x64 made the error go away.  AnyCPU and x86 fail.  Does this mean I have to create 2 versions of the EXE for my 32bit and 64bit workstations?

Comment: This article may help: [Using 32-bit or 64-bit ActiveX Components on x64 Windows](http://cknotes.com/using-32-bit-or-64-bit-activex-components-on-x64-windows/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily mean you have to create two instances.  You should be able to create just one as long as you make it AnyCPU.  The thing is, you have to register it with the correct runtime.  By default, Visual Studio registers AnyCPU with the 32-bit runtime on a 64-bit machine.  If you make sure to run the regasm.exe with the 64-bit runtime and correct version of the runtime, then you should be able to call it from a 64-bit process.

However, in my shop we've generally compiled one for x86 and one for x64 and deploy the right one for the right platform.

Comment: I actually have a lot of experience with this and for some reason was just having bad day.  In trying to narrow down the cause I had switched from Any CPU to x86 but failed to noticed the "Prefer 32bit"  option.  I incorrectly assumed my process was running 64bit and marked that off as a possible cause.  This left me backed up in a corner stressed out asking what could possibly be causing something so simple.